# How to get a row from the SQLITE db whose element in a particular column is the least

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to get a cursor which contains one row and the entry in a particular column of that row should be least when compared to corresponding entries in other rows.

The query that i am using is:

```
       mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_2, new String[] { "min (" +KEY_TIMEOUT+ ")", KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_UNIV }, null, null, null, null);
```

this is not returning anything. Is there a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to get a cursor which contains one row

then set a limit on the amount of rows: `LIMIT 1`

> and the entry in a particular column of that row should be least when compared to corresponding entries in other rows.

You can sort by that column so the smallest value in that column is first: `ORDER BY column`

That should result in

```
mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_2, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_UNIV },
        null, null, null, null, KEY_TIMEOUT, "1");
```